# qgis errpr :The following layers were not correctly generated

Tags: qgis, r

[image]

[image]

I am a novice, is this what is the problem?

Comment: Please add textual description of what you are doing and details of the problem.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Please take a [tour] and provide more information about your problem. For example what you have done, what you want achieve. You can edit your question easily, with improved question you will have higher chance to get proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message tells you have tried to run an R script in the Processing Toolbox, which requires `.rsx` scripts.

Please read `QGIS processing guide`, especially [R syntax in Processing](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/processing/r_syntax.html#r-syntax) part.